# Error Message for GrammarRules and GrammarApply

Tags: warning-messages, built-in-symbols, cloud-deploy

I have been struggling with the following issue regarding an irregularity when deploying and applying GrammarRules. Specifically, it often takes several failed attempts before the execution is successful.

The following is a simple example where I observe such an irregularity. Namely, for those attempts which fail, the error message is the following:

```
grammar1 = 
 CloudDeploy[
  GrammarRules[{FixedOrder[x : GrammarToken["GivenName"], 
      y : GrammarToken["SemanticNumber"]] :> x -> y}]]
```

[image: Error Message]

```
$Failed
```

The below is the detailed error message for this case:

[image]

The same problem occurs when applying GrammarApply to a successfully deployed GrammarRule:

```
GrammarApply[grammar1, "Joan 1289"]
```

[image: Error Message]

```
$Failed
```

The below is the detailed error message for this case:

[image]

Here again, it often takes several attempts until it actually works.

Any advice or hints on how to deal with this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks